# How to get this in loop

Tags: php, magento

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [item_variation_id] => 2
            [item_index] => 3146
            [rothco_item_no] => 10002
            [upc] => 023063601212
            [inventory] => 99
            [created_date] => 2014-11-28 10:06:45.000
            [weight] => .4000
            [image_filename] => 10002-A.jpg
            [catalog_page_no] => 183
            [msrp] => 20.9900
            [map] => .0000
            [diameter] => 
            [price] => 8.100000
            [case_price] => 
            [case_quantity] => 
            [statuses] => 
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [item_variation_id] => 5
            [item_index] => 2654
            [rothco_item_no] => 10005
            [upc] => 023063100227
            [inventory] => 99
            [created_date] => 2002-04-21 21:00:00.000
            [weight] => .1500
            [image_filename] => 10005-A.jpg
            [catalog_page_no] => 183
            [msrp] => 10.9900
            [map] => .0000
            [volume] => 22 Grams
            [price] => 4.200000
            [case_price] => 4.200000
            [case_quantity] => 
            [statuses] => 
        ));
```

This is my array $item_variation

I want to take this in loop, but as it is object array it is generating problem

I have tried this one, but it executes only once

and comes out of the loop

```
foreach ($item_variations as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
            if($k==$attributeCode)
            {
                if($v != ''){
                    Mage::log($v,NULL,"value.log");
                    $values[]=$v; 
                }

            }
         }
     }
```

So suggest solution to run this array in loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach ($item_variations as $key => $object) {
    $vars = get_object_vars($object);
    foreach ($vars as $k => $v) {
        if($k==$attributeCode) {
                if($v != ''){
                    Mage::log($v,NULL,"value.log");
                    $values[]=$v; 
                }
            }
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use $key => $object instead of $key => $value. because your array is object

foreach ($item_variations as $key => $object) {
    $vars = get_object_vars($object);
    foreach ($vars as $k => $v) {
        if($k==$attributeCode) {
                if($v != ''){
                    Mage::log($v,NULL,"value.log");
                    $values[]=$v; 
                }
            }
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, it will work for your need:

```
foreach ($item_variations as $item) {  
  foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
    if ($key == $attributeCode && !empty($value)) {
      Mage::log($value,NULL,"value.log");
      $values[]=$value;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi there please try this solution if you have not found one yet. Based on your array data you should have array like in this format.

```
$item_variations = array($stdClassobj1, $stdClassobj2);
    //to get loop going
     foreach($item_variations as $items){
       echo "item_variation_id:".$items->item_variation_id;
       echo "iteam Index:".$items->item_index;
       // you can do any further filter here using if else

     }
```

I have not test it but this is the way you should loop.